# Access Form - how to remove extra linked table from "Fields available for this view"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Access 2013 is unable to save a form because of an extra unwanted table, how to remove it? Access auto added the table and does not look to provide a way to remove it.

I added the table by mistake, using "Design" -> "Add existing fields" -> "Show All Tables" -> "Fields in related tables"  ... Clicking a table and adding a field to the form. This auto adds the table under section: "Fields available for this view"

Is there away way to remove the table. I have removed the field from the form but the table is still listed.

Re-creating the form is the only option I can think of, but the form has lots of tabs and so that would be a lot of work. Any other ideas?

Comment: can you right-click the table on the left side of the workspace and delete it?

Comment: @mdialogo you can, but the popup menu does not have a delete option.  It has a "edit record source", but clicking it give a "not available" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form Design view, open the **property sheet** of the form, tab "Data".

There you can edit the `RecordSource` property: click the `...` button and remove the unwanted table. Its fields will be deleted automatically from the recordsource.

Edit: just noticed that "edit record source" does the same. If that doesn't work, try closing the database, and perhaps do a Compact & Repair.

Comment: Works via form properties -> RecordSource, thanks. 

Strange, it still fails via right click "Edit record source". Maybe because my tables are sharepoint lists.

Comment: Compact & Repair causes the DB to fail, it looks to rename things.

Comment: @eddyparkinson: perhaps you have Object Name AutoCorrect enabled? See http://allenbrowne.com/bug-03.html